# Returned object from angularJS service is oddly formed

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-promise

I have a service in Angular:

```js
  /* App Module */
var triviaApp = angular.module('triviaApp', ['ngRoute', 'ngResource', 'ngCookies','ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap']);
  
  triviaApp.service('GameService', ['$rootScope', '$log', '$http', '$resource', '$location', function($rootScope, $log, $http, $resource, $location) {
    
     this.newGame = function(playerId, aiLevel, opponentId) {
  console.log('newGame - init');
  
  return $http({
   url: triviaAppConfig.rootAPIUrl + 'Players/' + playerId + '/Games?aiLevel=' + aiLevel + '&OpponentId=' + opponentId,
   method: "POST",
   })
   .then(function(response) {    
    return response.data;
   }, function(response) {
    $log.warn('Error in $http - getGames in controller...');
  });
 
 } 
    
    }]);
```

Here's my controller that calls my service and attaches it to the newGameBtn directive....

```js
  // HOME CONTROLLER
  triviaApp.controller('HomeController', ['$rootScope', '$scope', '$http', '$cookies', 'GameService', '$log',
    function($rootScope, $scope, $http, $cookies, GameService, $log ) {

            // Initiate New Game Function
        $scope.newGameBtn = function(emailId, aiLevel, opponentId) {
        $scope.gameObj = GameService.newGame(emailId, aiLevel, opponentId);
            console.log($scope.gameObj);

        }


]);


</script>
```

```html
    <div class="col-md-6 new-game-button">
        <a href="" ng-click="newGameBtn(emailId, 'none', 0)">
            <img src="/img/home/player-vs-player.png" width="256" height="161" alt="Player Vs Player">
            <p>New auto-matched Game</p>
        </a>
    </div>
```

The issue I'm running in to is that $scope.gameObj is coming back as:

```js
d {$$state: Object}
$$state: Object
status: 1
value: Object
ActivePlayer: 40
ConsecutiveAnswerCount: 0
ConsecutiveAwardsCount: 0
EndTime: "0001-01-01T00:00:00"
GameId: 1168
GameRound: 0
IsAwardRound: false
IsEndOfTurnRound: false
IsGameOverRound: false
Player1: Object
Player1AnswerSeconds: 0
Player1Awards: Array[0]
Player1Score: 0
Player2: Object
Player2AnswerSeconds: 0
Player2Awards: Array[0]
Player2Score: 0
StartTime: "2015-09-28T15:45:09.5246982Z"
Status: "InProgress"
WinningPlayer: 0
__proto__: Object
__proto__: Object
__proto__: d
```

Now, from reading around it sounds like I'm getting the promise back and not the object, but the question I have is how do I rewrite the service and the controller to set $scope.gameObj as my object data and not a promise?

Comment: That sure looks like your game data ... A promise doesn't have properties like "Player1Score" and so on.

Comment: It is my data, but it's buried 3 levels deep in the d > $$state > value object, instead of the root object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the service return the promise:

```js
this.newGame = function(playerId, aiLevel, opponentId) {
  return $http({
    url: triviaAppConfig.rootAPIUrl + 'Players/' + playerId + '/Games?aiLevel=' + aiLevel + '&OpponentId=' + opponentId,
    method: "POST",
  });
}
```

And make your controller wait for its resolution:

```js
GameService.newGame(emailId, aiLevel, opponentId).then(function(response) {
  $scope.gameObj = response.data;
});
```

Comment: This works, but by removing the resolution of .then from the service to the controller, I've removed the ability to use that service to deliver that object to other controllers. Why doesn't the .then work to deliver the object when it's in the service, but works in the controller?